# AngularJS - Looping through ASYNC GET requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am a beginner in Javascript and AngularJS and am trying to do the below:

There is a service that takes a list as URLs as input and find their respective data in a local cache/repository custom service.

- If all are found, they are returned.
- If some are missing, the missing ones are fetched by making ASYNC calls to the API. They are also stored into the repository for future availability.

All received data are concatenated into a local "data" variable and sent as a single array of objects to the controller.

It is looping through each URL using $.map to fetch data and concat it to the local "data" variable. Once the loop is complete, it is returning the "data" variable.

**I am aware that this is not going to work and also the reason for it. But, am not able to figure out how to achieve this using an ASYNC design pattern.**

```
myService.factory("dataManagerService",["dataRepositoryService","dataFetchService",
    function(dataRepositoryService,dataFetchService)
    {
        var methodObj = {};

        methodObj.getObjData = function(urlList)
        {
            //URLs are used to fetch data from API and also to uniquely identify the fetched data. 
            //urlList is a list/array of URLs for which data is required.

            //Get all objects from data repository which are specified in the URL list.
            var data = dataRepositoryService.getData(urlList);

            //If repository did not have all objects specified from the URL list, fetch the missed objects.
            if (data.length < urlList.length)
            {

                //Get list of URL for which data was received from repository.
                var excludeURLList = $.map(data,
                    function(obj)
                    {
                        return obj.url;
                    }
                );

                //Get list of all URLs from urlList that are missing from excludeURLList
                var fetchUrlList = $.grep(urlList,
                    function(url)
                    {
                        return excludeURLList.indexOf(url) < 0;
                    }
                );

                //Loop through all URLs in fetchUrlList (for which data was not found in the repository)
                $.map(fetchUrlList,
                    function(url)
                    {
                        //Make a GET request to the API
                        dataFetchService.fetchData(url)
                        .then(
                            function(response)
                            {
                                //Add the received response to the repository, so that its available the next time.
                                dataRepositoryService.setData(response.data);

                                //Append missing data to "data" variable
                                data.concat(response.data);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
            return data; /* This will be incomplete since it will be returned before all the async calls have been completed. */
        }

        return methodObj;
    }
]);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're going to want to use $q.all() to retrieve all of the URLS. Here's a pretty good article on this: https://www.martin-brennan.com/using-q-all-to-resolve-multiple-promises/

You're going to want to do something like this:

```
getObjectList(urlList) {
   var promises =[]
   urlList.map( function(url) { promise.push(getUrl(url) } )
   $q.all(promises).then( function(responses) { assemble what you want to return here}
  )


}

function getUrl(url) {
    var q=$q.defer()
    if (whereever you've stored the data has fetched the url already) {
         return $q.when(the data) 
    } else {
          return $http.get(url).then( function(response) {
              return $q.resolve(response.data)
          }, function (error) { return $q.reject(error) })
    }

}
```

Comment: That worked for me. But can you let me know why we are using $q.defer() in the getUrl() method? Just the result of $http is itself a promise, which we require for the $q.all() method.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad that worked. The only reason I used $q.defer was so that I could return just the data object, still wrapped in a promise. If just $http.get is returned, then you'll get a full response object back.